# ReactJS receiving empty array from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to send some simple data from the backend to the ReactJS API. However, ReactJS doesn't seem to receive it. ReactJS just receives an empty string. This is the code for both. Node is running in port 3000 and React on port 4000.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const a = "Hello world"


// app.use(cors())
app.use(cors({
        origin:"http://localhost:4000",
        methods:"GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
        credentials:true
    }))

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
})

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    console.log("someone is here")
    res.json({
        data:a
    })

})


app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running")
})
```

**Homepage.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Homepage extends Component {

    state = {
        authenticated: false,
        data:[]
    };

     componentDidMount(){
        const url = "http://localhost:3000/"
        axios.get(url)
        .then(r=>{
            console.log(r.json())
           return r.json()
        })
        .then(data=>this.setState({data}))
        console.log(this.state.data)
    }

    render() { 
        return ( <h1>{this.state.data ? this.state.data : "loading"}</h1> );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your node server.

You have defined a middleware to set specific response headers.

```js
// This block.
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization")
})
```

The issue is that you are not invoking the `next` parameter on the callback function, hence the middleware is not passing control to the `next` middleware (in your case, the route handlers)

The fix:

```js
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

    next();  // Add this line
})
```

**One important note about express middlewares:**

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the `next` middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging

Comment: Thank you! That fixed part of the problem! Now I have another: "TypeError: r.json is not a function"

Comment: You can access your value with `r.data`. Might help to console log the response from the api call. That way you can see and familiarize yourself with all the properties that are available to you.

Comment: Ah, I see! The information is stored inside another data object. So, I have to access it by doing "r.data.data". Thank you! I can do it with axios, however I can't do the same for a fetch(url), why is that? I don't see the data that I sent from the backend when I do a console.log

Comment: The reason you don't have to call `.json()` on the response object from axios is because it performs an automatic transformation of JSON data for you. If you use `fetch` you have to transform the response yourself.

Comment: Yes, I see! Thank you so much!